# How to check whether an ip address in a local network has a shared network folder. How is this possible with perl?

Tags: perl, directory, shared, shared-directory

How to check whether an ip address in a local network has a shared network folder.
How is this possible with perl?

Answer (score 2):

```
require IPC::System::Simple;
use autodie qw(:all);
system qw(smbclient -L 192.168.0.1);
```